# How can I create a Google Analytics Custom Report that shows which pages (by title) a Custom UserID visited?

Tags: google-analytics, report

I have successfully added the GA code to track custom user IDs as follows:

```
 <script>
    var user = "<?php echo $_SESSION['txtUserId']; ?>";
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'dimension1', '<?php echo $userID; ?>');
  ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'pageview',
    'title': 'Login Page'
    });
</script>
```

However, I haven't been able to show all of this info in the same custom report that I created.  I have the Metric Group set to "PageViews" and the Content Drilldowns "Page Title" and "UserID" but I cannot get all of this information to appear in one report.  I either see Pagetitle and Pageviews or Page Title with the number of hits.  I need to see the pages the UserID went to.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want url, titel and custom dimension displayed side by side ? Because that won't work, reports show two dimensions max (in flat table type of reports).

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff, I believe custom reports now support up to 5 dimensions, as of a few months ago.

Comment: I stand corrected! Thank you nyuen, I hadn't noticed.

Comment: Yeah, no problem! It took me by surprise as well when I first found out!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of custom reports and you should be able to see up to 5 dimensions per reports Or make use of the API and you will be able to see up to 7 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This should be very easy with CustomReports:

1. Select *Pageviews* as Metric
2. Select *Page Title* and *Client ID* (or User ID - either one depending on what you have stored in Custom Dimensions).

You should get what you need :)

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I've done but the actual report contains only Page TItle and Pageviews by default.  If I add Secondary Dimension userID - I get just the login page and one userID - I need to follow the user through the site and display all users, not just one.

Comment: Is you UserID dimensiion of SESSION or USER scope? It seems from what you describe it's HIT only, which should be changed :)

Comment: I'm using SESSION $_SESSION['keycode'] = $userId; which picks up the id OK but currently I'm not even getting the dimension to appear at all.  Is this correct? '  ga('set', 'dimension1', '<?php $userId; ?>');
  ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'pageview',
 'title': 'First Page',
 'userId': 'dimension1''

Comment: Have you set them up correctly in Admin section (> Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions)?

Comment: @user1356553 can you please go to *Edit Custom Report* try to set *Report Content* type to *Flat Table*. Then you'll be able to see your custom dimensions there.